# SAS dataset count winning streak on baseball

Tags: count, sas, data-processing, data-munging

Hi: I am processing baseball dataset. I want to count the winning streak of a team winning. I created a variable called win, if team A wins it is 1, else it is 0. I want to create a variable called winstreak, if team A wins 1 time, it is 1, if team A wins 2 in a row, it is 2, if team A loses it goes back to 0 again. So far I have tried:

```
data phi2002;
  set phi2002;
  retain winstreak;

  if (VisitingTeam = "PHI" and VisitorRunsScored > HomeRunsScore)
    then PHIWIN = 1;
  else if (HomeTeam = "PHI" and HomeRunsScore > VisitorRunsScored)
    then PHIWIN = 1;
  else PHIWIN = 0;

  if PHIWIN = 1 then winstreak =+1;
  else winstreak = 0;
run;
```

The code doesnt work, since winstreak only shows the same value as PHIWIN. Please help!

Comment: I'm assuming you mean streak not steak ;)

Comment: I don't know if this is valid SAS code 'winstreak =+1' try winstreak+1 instead.

Comment: I tried it, it just changes winsteak value to 2 instead of 1, but its the same as phiwin.

Comment: Thats because your else statement resets it. Change your else.

Comment: with the `=+` -> `+` correction it works for me

Comment: Thank you! It works for me now